# Asymptotic expansion in epsilon gets worse with more terms?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I'm trying to get an order bound on the following integral as $\epsilon \to 0$:

$$g(\epsilon) = \int_a^{a+\epsilon} f(\epsilon,v) dv$$ where $f$ is an ugly, but smooth, function when $0< a \leq v <a+\epsilon$. My issue is that when I attempt to expand $$g(\epsilon) = \epsilon f(0,a) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\big(2 f_\epsilon(0,a) + f_v(0,a)\big) + o(\epsilon^2),$$

I run into issues.  Namely, some terms go to infinity when evaluated at $\epsilon = 0$.  I also notice that, if I look (formally) at the same expansion without evaluating anything in $\epsilon$, the series order decreases with $\epsilon$ as I add more derivatives:  first $\epsilon^{-2}$, then $\epsilon^{-4}$, and so on.

Would someone please explain to me what is going on here? I don't understand how to extract a reasonable order bound in $\epsilon$ from this expansion if it continues to decrease as I add terms.  I have never done series calculations like this before, so a reference containing theory and/or examples would also be helpful.  Thanks,

Comment: this is the generic behaviour for an [asymptotic expansion:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Asymptotic_expansion) _In case the asymptotic expansion does not converge, for any particular value of the argument there will be a particular partial sum which provides the best approximation and adding additional terms will decrease the accuracy. "_

Comment: This review article "The Devil's Invention: Asymptotic, Superasymptotic
and Hyperasymptotic Series" by John P. Boyd discusses this in detail http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jpboyd/boydactaapplicreview.pdf